# Android jwplayer video doesn't play in my activity

Tags: android, android-activity, jwplayer

When the activity launch, I can briefly see a loading sign before he disapear, but nothing happend after. I follow all the step from https://developer.jwplayer.com/sdk/android/docs/developer-guide/usage/jwplayer-view/ , but nothing works.

My xml page have a TextView and Imageview inside a linearLayout.
I check the response of my request, if there is a video, I catch the url and add it to the playerConfig:

```
    PlayerConfig playerConfig = new PlayerConfig.Builder()
            .file("http://videos.videos-mdr.com/20170108/sparrow-frozen-to-fence-rescue.mp4")
            .autostart(true)
            .build();

    // Instantiate a new JWPlayerFragment using the playerConfig
    JWPlayerView playerView = new JWPlayerView(this, playerConfig);
    linearLayout.addView(playerView);
```

post.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llayout_article"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorVideoMdr"
            app:titleTextColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/title_article"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/date_article"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:textSize="13dp"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

EDIT: I can see the video when I add :

```
            playerView.setMinimumHeight(this.convertPxInDpi(300, context));
```

before the linearLayout.addView(playerView);
The problem is when I switch to fullscreen Mode, it keep the maxheight ...
Is there another way to fix a specific height instead of setMinimumHeight?

Comment: add your xml code

Comment: ok I just added my post.xml